# Counting the most amount of items assigned to a user using greatest

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query 5 separate tables in my mysql database, and display the actor with the most amount of items assigned to them. The table structures are as follows;

```
item
itemid | item | description | brand | date | time | path |

actor
actorid | name | actorthumb | bio |

brand
brandid | brandname | description | image |

movie
movieid | title | genre | year | moviethumb | synopsis|

request
requestid | userid | itemid | brandid | movieid | actorid | content | requestdate |
```

I presume I need to join the request, actor and items table together, using COUNT function count how many items are assigned to an actor, then use GREATEST to display the actor with the highest amount of items assigned to them?

```
The query to join all the tables is 
$query = "SELECT greatest i.*, a.*, b.*, m.*, r.* FROM item AS i, actor AS a, brand AS    b, movie AS m, request AS r
    WHERE r.itemid = i.itemid 
    AND r.actorid = a.actorid
    AND r.brandid = b.brandid
    AND r.movieid = m.movieid";
```

Please confirm the best way to do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.actorid, a.name
    FROM request r
        INNER JOIN actor a
            ON r.actorid = a.actorid
    GROUP BY a.actorid, a.name
    ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT r.itemid) DESC
    LIMIT 5
```

Comment: OK thanks what is the best way to display the content once I have inserted this query? I am using a while loop and the LIMIT command?

Comment: What's the purpose of the while loop? This should only return one value.

Comment: I want to display the top 5 actors, we also want to make these clickable so when you click on the actor it takes you to the actors page. I am using the following;

Comment: @Martin: Simply change the LIMIT to 5. As for display and making the items clickable, that's beyond the scope of this simple SQL guy's capabilities.

Comment: OK Thanks Joe, I can make the items clickable however when I click on each result its doesn't display the actors page because the query doesnt select the actorid it only selects the name? Please how can I modify the query to ask for actorid aswell as name?

Comment: Add the actorid to both the SELECT and GROUP BY. I'll modify the answer to reflect this as well.

Comment: @Martin: Glad to help. Please mark this answer as accepted (click the check mark next to it) when you are able. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. I think it needs clarifying that if an item has been assigned to an actor several times, either for the same movie or for different movies, then the item will be counted once.

Answer (score 0):

```
The query to join all the tables is 
$query = "SELECT i.*, a.*, b.*, m.*, r.* FROM item AS i, actor AS a, brand AS    b, movie AS m, request AS r
    WHERE r.itemid = i.itemid 
    AND r.actorid = a.actorid
    AND r.brandid = b.brandid
    AND r.movieid = m.movieid
    ORDER BY count(i.*) DESC";
```